# Rails: Begin Rescue block not being called in private method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refactoring

In my rails app I have this bit of logic in my `SessionsController`'s `create` method that I want to refactor out by extracting it into a method:

```
if login_form.validate(params[:user])
  begin
    @user = User.find_by!(email: params[:user][:email])
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => e
    flash.now.alert = 'invalid user credentials'
    render :new and return
  end
else
  flash.now.alert = login_form.errors.full_messages
  render :new and return
end
```

All this does is check if user exists in the system. I want to refactor this into

```
if login_form.validate(params[:user])
  find_user
else
  flash.now.alert = login_form.errors.full_messages
  render :new and return
end
```

And then the private `find_user` method:

```
  private
  def find_user
    begin
      @user = User.find_by!(email: params[:user][:email])
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => e
      flash.now.alert = 'invalid user credentials'
      render :new and return
    end
  end
```

But now after I do this, the  `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` exception is ignored! The method does not stop at the `return` command. Why is that? What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:

I understand what I am doing wrong. But how do I do this in the right way?

Answer (score 1):

The return statement just returns from the function where it is called, that is the find_user method.

Comment: So what is the proper way to do this?

Comment: Doesn't the validate function of the login form check the password/user? I would probably put that check there and then you can skip the exception handling and you don't need the find_user method.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I can use a block like so:

```
   if login_form.validate(params[:user])
      find_user do
        flash.now.alert = 'invalid user credentials'
        render :new and return
      end
    else
      flash.now.alert = login_form.errors.full_messages
      render :new and return
    end
```

And then refactor the private method like so:

```
  def find_user(&block)
    begin
      @user = User.find_by!(email: params[:user][:email])
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => e
      yield
    end
  end
```

Comment: I would not send a block to the find_user message like that, this code does not increase readability compared to your original code.